# Sum numbers using loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My objective: write an application that uses while loop to get 20 inputs from a user and displays the sum of all those numbers.

I get how to do the while loop but I don't know how to get the sum of all those numbers (because the variable will be the same). Here is what I have so far:

```
Scanner Numb = new Scanner (System.in); 
int count = 0;
while (count<20) {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int numb = Numb.nextInt();
    count++;
```

Comment: Testing a program with ***20*** user inputs is a nightmare. Consider populating an int array with twenty elements, with 20 user inputs, then pass the array into to a `getSum(i[])` function. Then you can create test-data without having to enter...in...all...twenty...numbers...every...SINGLE...time... Ugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a common variable to store sum

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
while (count<20) {
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int numb = Numb.nextInt();
    sum = sum+numb;
    count++;
}
System.out.println("sum is "+sum);
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the help. The while loop looks good otherwise right?

Comment: Will do so as soon as the system lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

you need another variable to add it to that is outside the while loop.

Comment: Examples are usually helpful.